# How to print Array Values in Prestashop PDF

Tags: php, pdf, prestashop, tcpdf

I already tried, ppp($this->order), ppp($order), print_r($this->order).....

but i just get a blank Page on invoice Download also with and without Debug Mode???

Anyone can help please ?

Comment: In which file you want to print array (some php or tpl file)? Or what you wanna get?

Comment: Sorry i dont know wehre i should get it exactly....I tried in in a override/classes/HTMLInvoiceTemplate.php file and hoped they apperaed after i click for download the PDFInvoice..or on the downloaded PDF invoice......but just a blank page :( I try to see what all can be used on the PDF Invoice. Hope you understand what i want sry for bad english.

Comment: Better way is printing in tpl smarty object, you can do this in pdf folder, using {$variable|d} or  {$variable|var_dump}

Comment: Yeah Man Realy Nice, This is exactly what i searched for. Big and Fat Thank You :)